# Creating and adding a toolbar to an AppCompatActivity programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I am trying to set the toolbar for a class that extends AppCompatActivity programmatically, but the activity does not have a toolbar when it is run.  Every tutorial I have been able to find on using toolbars have the toolbar being created and added in XML, but I am looking for a better way to add the toolbar to all my activities, so I am trying to do it programmatically.  However, the toolbar is either not visible or not added when I run, and I cannot find the problem.  This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, R.attr.actionBarSize);
        toolbar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        toolbar.setPopupTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        toolbar.setTitle("This is the title");
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

And this is my XML file `activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my toolbar.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't understand why not using XML is any easier or less verbose.

Comment: Refer : https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-Toolbar#reusing-the-toolbar

Answer (score 5):

Add `Toolbar` to your `Activity` layout using `YOUR_LAYOUT.addView(toolbar, 0)`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 168);
        toolbar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        toolbar.setPopupTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        toolbar.setTitle("This is the title");
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Assuming in activity_main, you are using LinearLayout as root  
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_linear_layout);
        ll.addView(toolbar, 0);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Use `MainActivity` theme `AppTheme.NoActionBar` to avoid `RuntimeException`:

> This `Activity` already has an `action bar` supplied by the window decor.
>   Do not request `Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR` and set
>   `windowActionBar` to `false` in your theme to use a `Toolbar` instead.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: What if I want to use the toolbar from appcompatv7 instead of the standard toolbar? i.e. how to create an `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` toolbar programmatically? Saying `new android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar(this)` obviously doesn't work.